# htaccess rewrite to wildcard subdomain explained

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

dear community.
Today i made this .htaccess rewrite rules ( found some part on the internet and added some by myself )

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).site.com/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %1.php
```

When i request *some.site.ru* - *site.ru/some.php* content triggered. It's fine. And when i request *some.site.ru/readme.txt* i see *site.ru/readme.txt* content. And i dont quite understand why its working fine.
I thought `RewriteRule ^ %1.php` makes all requests to go through *.php files. Am i wrong?

Additionally i cant understand `RewriteRule ^` this part. Is it the same as `RewriteRule ^(.*)$` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your rule:

```sh
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).site.com/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %1.php
```

Due to presence of faulty pattern in front of `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` it is a **DO NOTHING** rule, in other words this rule will never execute because of presence of a `/` in 2nd condition which can never be true because `%{HTTP_HOST}` matches only the host name part of a web request. So `%{HTTP_HOST}` can only match `www.example.ru` or `example.ru`.

So it is obvious that `/readme.txt` URL is working fine without any rewrite.

Comment: Wow, ty a lot for explanation. so it was that kind of mistake that made a trick after all lol.